# How to programmatically restore and backup using android auto backup

Tags: android, sqlite, google-drive-api, sharedpreferences, backup

I have an app that has an SQLite db and shared pref, and what I want is to control when to backup and restore them programmatically.

I read in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html#java) that android auto backup takes care of this automatically, and stores it to Google Drive located in the Backup Folder, but I would like to do this myself and later store it in the same location

Is it possible

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a custom server-side application as your backup and restore source.
You will need to create a server-side application and develop logic on the server to upload user data and on user sign in you can download this data to the user's device.